# sql server how to retrieve a full tree given any child?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tree

I have a table with id and parent_id. I have seen many CTE on how to generate the tree. However I can't seem to filter the tree in order to retrieve a full tree given any node from it.

Given the values

```
1, NULL
2, 1
3, 2
4, 2
5, NULL
6, 5
7, NULL
```

If I filter by id any of the values 1,2,3 or 4 I should get the tree

```
1, NULL
2, 1
3, 2
4, 2
```

for 5 or 6

```
5, NULL
6, 5
```

for 7

```
7, NULL
```

Can this be achieved using CTE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one CTE to locate the root of the tree, and then use a second CTE to explode the tree structure:

```
declare @T table (ID int not null, Parent int null)

insert into @T(ID,Parent) values
(1, NULL),
(2, 1   ),
(3, 2   ),
(4, 2   ),
(5, NULL),
(6, 5   ),
(7, NULL)

declare @Node int
set @node = 3

;With Root as (
    select t.ID,t.Parent from @T t where t.ID = @Node or t.Parent = @Node
    union all
    select t.ID,t.Parent
    from
        Root r
            inner join
        @t t
            on
                t.ID = r.Parent
), Tree as (
    select ID,Parent from Root where Parent is null
    union all
    select t.ID,t.Parent
    from @T t
        inner join
        Tree tr
            on tr.ID = t.Parent
)
select * from Tree
```

Result:

```
ID          Parent
----------- -----------
1           NULL
2           1
3           2
4           2
```

Hopefully you can see how the two CTEs are working in opposite directions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursive CTE like this.
CTE returns all tree with RootId, and you could get all tree nodes by its RootId

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    NodeId int,
    ParentNodeId int
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
(
    NodeId,
    ParentNodeId
)
VALUES
( 1, NULL),
( 2, 1),
( 3, 2),
( 4, 2),
( 5, NULL),
( 6, 5),
( 7, NULL)

DECLARE @NodeId int = 4

-- temp returns all child nodes of rootid (1,5,7)
;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT sd.NodeId, sd.ParentNodeId, sd.NodeId AS RootId 
    FROM @SampleData sd
    WHERE sd.ParentNodeId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sd.NodeId, sd.ParentNodeId, t.RootId  
    FROM temp t
    INNER JOIN @SampleData sd ON t.NodeId = sd.ParentNodeId
)

SELECT t2.NodeId, t2.ParentNodeId 
FROM temp t
INNER JOIN temp t2 ON t2.RootId = t.RootId
WHERE t.NodeId = @NodeId
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/PPPMXX4941